# How to launch Dockerized app onto another computer

Tags: react-native, docker

I'm quite new to Docker and this question might seem trivial but there it is.

So I've dockerized a brand new React Native app (As a proof of concept) on my Computer A, and the container works fine but after taking out the container onto my Computer B (I transform it into a .tar.gz file then load and run the image) I have this error :
[Error no such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBjYM.png)

It works on Computer A with the react project being in the same folder as the Dockerfile, but when I launch the container on Computer B it tells me that it can't find the app folder even when imported on the computer

Feel free to ask any question since I know my explanations can be troubled.

Edit to Answer larsks :

A : I get my .tar.gz file with `docker save app | gzip -> testApp.tar.gz`

B :I then transfer my container with `scp testApp.tar.gz second@computer`

C : I run the image with `docker load < testApp.tar.gz` then `docker run app`

D : The exact output is

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Edit2 :

Dockerfile :

```
FROM arm64v8/node:14
COPY qemu-aarch64-static /usr/bin

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
      - 19006:19006
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dev
      - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
```

The app is simply the app from the base project of React native
`npx create-expo-app app`

Comment: It would help if you could update your question to include the *specific commands* involved here, particularly (a) how did you transform it into a `.tar.gz` file? (b) How did you load it onto computer B? (c) Exactly how did you run the image? (d) What was the exact output of the command you ran in (c)?

Comment: Thanks larsks, I've updated my post as to have every answer in the post

Comment: Please don't post images of text: just include the text itself in the question (formatted as a code sample). That makes things easier to read. It really helps if your question has a [mcve]: something we can run locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Can you add the content of your Dockerfile (or a minimal version that still reproduces the problem)?

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually `COPY` your application code into the image?

Comment: You’re right, just before reading your comment I added an ADD (instead of copy) and I’m still having an error, but not the same. The project is having an expo error, which I’ll look more into tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't use ADD in my dockerfile so the container didn't included my app file.

Add this to Dockerfile :

```
ADD /app ./
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the Dockerfile contents? From first look seems that the folder you navigating '/app/package.json' doesn't exist and npm command executed inside container couldn't find that file.

Comment: ` WORKDIR /app CMD["npm", "start"] `
I know it can't seem to find it, but as said even when I Import the /app folder the same error outputs